# Javascript - Recursion and promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this function :

```js
// This function just add `_x` to all key and `_y` to all values
var data = {
  glossary: {
    title: "example glossary",
    GlossDiv: {
      title: "S",
      GlossList: {
        GlossEntry: {
          ID: "SGML",
          SortAs: "SGML",
          GlossTerm: "Standard",
          Acronym: "SGML",
          Abbrev: "1986",
          GlossDef: {
            para: "DocBook.",
            GlossSeeAlso: "GMLXML"
          },
          GlossSee: "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function treee(data) {
  Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
    if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object') {
      treee(data[key]);
    }
    data[key + '_x'] = typeof data[key] === 'string' ? data[key] + '_y' : data[key];
    delete data[key];
  });
}


treee(data);
console.log(data);
```

I want to change his behaviors. I want `'_x'` to be a data I receive from http request (I am using npm,  you can see doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) ): 
I have tried fiew things to make it work but still not working good.
This is how I made it :

```js
var data = {
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISo",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": "GMLXML"
          },
          "GlossSee": "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var http = require('request');

function treee(data) {
  Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      http({
          url: 'url',
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
          }
        },
        function(err, res, body) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('err');
            console.log(err);
            resolve("err")
          }

          if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object') {
            treee(data[key]);
          }
          resolve(body.data)
        }
      );
    }).then(function(d) {
      data[key + d.x] = typeof data[key] === 'string' ? data[key] + '_y' : data[key];
      delete data[key];
    });
  });
}

treee(data);

console.log(data);
```

My question is how can I get Data from network and add to my json. I Want almost the same behaviors except that `_x` comes from http request ...
Thanks

Comment: Both of your code snippets return errors.  What is your question?

Comment: The `console.log(data)` call happens **before** the promise is resolved, i.e. before any changes to `data` have been made. However, since browsers do weird things when logging objects, this might not actually be part of the issue.

Comment: *"but still not working good"* Can you elaborate on that? I assume you mean that it is not working, but how exactly is it not working? What happens?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it is clear now

Comment: `Promise.all`... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith But I would like to return and object (json) instead of array. That is why I was trying to modify my object through reference. I  don't see how to use Promise.all to do this.

Comment: First off, you can't return *anything* other than a Promise or a data structure of Promises. Period. But Promises are just boxes. And transforming an array to a hashtable is straightforward, you just have to do it *inside* the Promise from Promise.all and assign that result to a name. Now you have a promise of a hash instead of a Promise of an array, which you can further manipulate by calling `.then()` on it again.

Comment: On a side note, there simply is no way that this question is going to fly on SO. Your edit made it clear, but now its a dupe of how to return a result from an asynchronous function.